# How to format a string of nine digits in Python?

Tags: python, string, pandas, string-formatting

I have a range of string such as: `"024764108"`, `"002231531"`,  `"005231329"`, they have exactly 9 digits. And I want to add `-` to each group of 3 digits. The result I want is as below:
`"024-764-108"`, `"002-231-531"`, `"005-231-329"`.
How can I explain my think to python?

Comment: @Mulliganaceous  I think is a string, because if is digital, it will lose the zero in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a dynamic solution:

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]:
               num
0        024764108
1        002231531
2        005231329
3  012345678901234

In [42]: df.num.str.extractall(r'(\d{3})').groupby(level=0)[0].apply('-'.join)
Out[42]:
0            024-764-108
1            002-231-531
2            005-231-329
3    012-345-678-901-234
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

If using python 3.6 you could consider 'f strings', f strings allow you to do some processing within the string.

```
f'{string[:3]}-{string[3:6]}-{string[6:]}'
```

Another option would be to split your string into three parts then do a join on the array.

```
split_string = [string[i: i + 3] for i in range(0, len(string), 3)]
formated_number = '-'.join(split_string)
```

The first line of this creates an array with sub strings of length 3, then it joins the elements of that array with a '-' character in between.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way to do this but you can use `[]` to split the string into sections of 3.

```
old_str = "024764108"
new_str = old_str[:3] + '-' +  old_str[3:6] + '-' + old_str[6:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code, using string slicing: The segment of code that converts this str to your format is `string[0:3] + "-" + string[3:6] + "-" + string[6:9]`

Here is your updated method and some test cases. Also, it only accepts outputs which contain exactly 9 digits.

```
def format_digitstring(string:str):
    if len(string) != 9:
        return None
    return string[0:3] + "-" + string[3:6] + "-" + string[6:9]

s1 = "024764108"
s2 = "002231531"
s3 = "005231329"
s4 = "00112341"

print(format_digitstring(s1))
print(format_digitstring(s2))
print(format_digitstring(s3))
print(format_digitstring(s4))
```

Output:

```
024-764-108
002-231-531
005-231-329
None
```

Comment: it do works for me! Thanks. But in addition, I want to if I can use format to do this work, .format()

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution:

```
number = "024764108"
new_number = number[:3] + '-' + number[3:6]+ '-' + number[6:]
```

Answer (score 0):

This also do:

```
import re
s='024764108'
print(('{}-'*2+'{}').format(*re.findall('(...)',s)))
```

or if you want to do it on all row, you can use panda's apply function.

Answer (score 0):

Look ahead positive, \d{3} means three digits which followed with digit (?=\d), '-' is added after three digits ('\1-').

```
import re
number="024764108"
re.sub(r'(\d{3})(?=\d)',r'\1-',number)
```